# Drop down from off screen?

Tags: css

I have an animation applied to my form, I want it to drop down from the top of the screen as it fades in.

I have the fade in property set and it works like a charm, but now I need it to slide in from the top. Also I need my table to appear first. I want it to pop in. How would I do this?

Here is my form CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeIn{
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}


form {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 2s;}
```

Here is my table CSS:

```
table{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    width: 330px;
    white-space: 5px;}


table {border-collapse: collapse;}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #ccc;}



table caption{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    background-color: #999;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;}
```

Any help on this would be great! Thanks again!

Here is all the HTML I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oregano' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/project4.css" type="text/css">
<title>SylviaGunter WEB-210 Project 4</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="process.php">
<h1>Registration</h1>
<ol>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="required" type="text" id="email" name="email">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label>
        <input  class="required" type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </li>
</ol>
</form>

<table>
<caption>Last five new registrants</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Aaron Aaronson</td>
        <td>1/1/14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Becky Beckinson</td>
        <td>1/1/14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charlie Charleson</td>
        <td>1/1/14</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Devon Devons</td>
        <td>1/1/14</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Edward Edwards</td>
        <td>1/1/14</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.com with your working example? It's hard to understand what you need

Comment: @Sylvia585 please provide html code or jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

I think that's you need.

```
  @keyframes fadeIn{
     from {opacity: 0; top: -400px;}
     to {opacity: 1; top: 0;}
  }
  form {
      position: relative;
  }
```

Here you are the edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s57rsxd9/1/

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't provide a working fiddle. See the comments in the post please

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I don't even know what a fiddle is! I'm a rookie at this. Why cant you just look at the code? Is there an "appear" @keyframe that'll make my table appear? Can I use more than one (keyframes) with different names?

Comment: Just enter in jsfiddle.com and fill the css and html. You provide us a working example with that. It's hard to say to you how to make it. The best way is absolute positioning, as I put in my example. With absolute positioning you can control top and left your element and move it against the entire screen.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s57rsxd9/   There, I think that's right. Now that you can see it... I need the form to slide in from the top... and that table needs to suddenly appear (first) and stay there.

Answer (score 0):

hi as you want to create dropdown effect so that in animation you first need give from which position you want to start and end i think this two parameters will work what you want please check out

so you can get this by

```css
 @keyframes fadeIn{
     from {opacity: 0; top: 0;}
     to {opacity: 1; top: 100%;}
  }
```

Comment: When I type this in, it takes my animation away completely.

Comment: @Sylvia585 Please provide your html code with question